# diferencias entre 0, null y espacio vacío en java, c,c++ y python

Tags: java, python, c++, c

Mediante unas pruebas, he apreciado que mientras java y c no permiten declarar un array con tamaño [null] o [ ], C++ sí que permite el primero y python permite ambos.

Veo lógico que Java y C no permitan esta práctica ya que null no es un valor de tipo int y el tamaño de un array debe serlo, además de que "null" como tal no es un valor, sino que indica la ausencia de valores.

Por ello, me gustaría saber:

1.- ¿Por qué unos lenguajes lo permiten y otros no?

2.- ¿Qué tipo de valores requiere cada lenguaje para indicar el tamaño de arrays?

3.- ¿Qué diferencia hay entre 0 y null?

Aún no pudiendo responder a las tres cuestiones agradecería recibir respuesta a al menos una.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 4):

Voy a responder a tus dudas aunque no esté de acuerdo con tu pregunta:

1. ¿Por qué unos lenguajes lo permiten y otros no?
   Sencillamente porque el creador del lenguaje quiso que fuera así.
2. ¿Qué tipo de valores requiere cada lenguaje para indicar el tamaño de arrays?
   Un entero, siempre. No puedes definir un Array de `[0.397]` elementos.
3. ¿Qué diferencia hay entre 0 y null?
   `NULL` en C es una macro que expande a `((void *)0)` en algunas plataformas, en otras expande simplemente a `0`.
   En C++ `NULL` sigue siendo una macro, la cual desconozco su valor, sin embargo `nullptr` es una palabra reservada para asignar `null` a un puntero.
   En python no existe `null` *(Que yo sepa)*. conozco `None` y es exactamente lo mismo; en Python no existen Arrays, sino [List Comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk), por ello es de entender que puedas crear un `list(None)`, pues puedes introducir objetos luego.

Pero básicamente la diferencia entre NULL y 0 es una palabra y un número, en todos los contextos, el significado de cada una en su respectivo lenguaje es diferente y amerita una pregunta por lenguaje *(Por esto no estoy de acuerdo con tu pregunta)*.

Answer (score 0):

quisiera despejar en la mayor manera tus dudas, y quiero aclarar que a pesar de que Python aún no lo he estudiado (a penas y empezaré a trabajar con tal lenguaje) pero quiero colaborar.. empiezo:

1) Tu primer pregunta es algo complicada de responder, creo que eso depende de como está diseñado la manera de como compila / interpreta cada lenguaje su sintaxis.

2) Como imagino sabrás, hay distintas maneras de instanciar un array en los distintos lenguajes, puede que definas desde un inicio su valor entre los corchetes: numeros[2]=15; también puedes asignar valores de la siguiente forma: int[] numeros={2, -4, 15, -25}; (donde el número de valores que van entre las llaves define el length del array) o además puedes que necesites que de ingresar de forma "calculada" cierto valores en un array, entonces puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

for(int i=0; i

3) Cero (0) es un valor entero, mientras que null, es una referencia nula, que no hace referencia a ningún objeto.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

1)Para empezar en c y Java si que puedes declarar un por ejemplo int Array[]={1,2,3}
pero siempre tienes que introducir los valores en la declaración para que el compilador pueda reservar la memoria necesaria. Internamente si no inicializaras el vector apuntaria a una zona de memoria sin almacenar datos, lo cual es un error.

2)
En c int numeros[10]
En Java int[] numeros =new int[4];

3) 0 es un entero, es decir un valor, que pueden ser numero de elementos, numero a operar
NULL se utiliza en logica de punteros, es decir un puntero que apunta a NULL no apunta a nunguna zona de memoria